# Public Key Encryption

Tags: c#, encryption, public-key-encryption

I was thinking about communication between two computers using public-key encryption.

Let us assume that on one computer side I generate a private key and a public key.  If I send the public key to the other computer, can it still be captured by a packet sniffer and use it to decrypt my message?  If yes, what can be done to prevent this and what is the use of public key encryption then?

**Update**

Is SSL equivalent to public-key encryption?  Should I use it instead?

Comment: Public means ... well... it's public, not secret. You should consult wikipedia on this.

Comment: Does SSL implement public key cryptography on its own?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The public key is not used to decrypt, but to encrypt. You decrypt with your private key. That way, only **you** can decrypt the message.

Usually though, private-public key encryption is too expensive to encrypt data with. You'd use a private/public encryption scheme to exchange a shared key (large random number) to encrypt your data with.

Example: Alice creates a private/public keypair, sends the public key to Bob. Bob creates a large random number and encrypts it with Alice's public key. Alice can decrypt that and find the large random number. Alice and Bob then use the random number to encrypt their data stream.

As additional security, you could change keys periodically.

To update on your SSL question: it works exactly as I describe above. See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security

Comment: That's not right, you can also use private key to encrypt and public key to decrypt. The key can make client know it was connecting to a "legal" server, but can't help server to ensure it's a "legal" client since key stored at client side or send from server can be leaked. A better solution is implement your own algorithm to prevent being hacked.

Comment: Using the public key to decrypt means **everybody** can decrypt your message and it has nothing to do with encryption, but with **authentication**, which is something completely different.

Comment: In RSA theory you are right, but this means only one side can be ensured legal. Let's think about bank website, the client should know he is on legal website, but bank server doesn't need to ensure the client is legal or not since `mobile phone authentication` and other methods can do the trick. The `mobile phone authentication` is just something like "hash method", so, hash method is a must. RSA alone can not ensure safety.

Comment: @ReckHou In your example, you'd use quite different systems, using certificates, certificate authorities and a "web of trust". RSA alone can be used, for example by using a signature scheme. (Server creates a plaintext and signs it with private key; client then verifies the signature and plaintext using public key. No hashing involved and authenticity of server is ensured.)

Comment: Your example is right, but how about the reverse situation, like server should verify client's request?

Comment: @ReckHou, although with some algorithms (e.g. RSA), you can *technically* "encrypt" with the private key, this is no longer encryption, but signing. While the "numbers" making up the private key and public key can have their roles swapped, doing so also effectively reverses the purpose of the keys, and thus their names. Bottom line, you *never* encrypt with the private key: you *sign* and *decipher* (and, you *verify a signature* and *encrypt* with a public key).

Comment: @Bruno both you and Bart's RSA theory is right, but you still have to consider Matt's situation that he want both of 2 computers to be ensured legal. And you STILL can't answer my question that how server can ensure client is legal. My point is RSA can only ensure 1 of them legal, instead of both of them.

Comment: @ReckHou, the problem is that Matthew wrongly assumed that the public key was used for decryption ("*If I send the public key, [...] use it to decrypt my message?*"). If it's about proving the client's identity, it should *sign* something with its private key (this is what is done in SSL/TLS with client cert auth).

Comment: @Bruno: First question, I think he's not clear with RSA algorithm so you are right. Second question, if we send key through internet that means "no encryption". If we stored key at local, cracker can obtain it through reverse engineering. So we have to make it much more complicated. A pathetic fact is, even companies with endless resources can fail completely, like Blizzard's WOW.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes, it can be captured by sniffer.

**Why RSA alone does not fit with Matt's situation?**

> In Matt's situation, he want both of 2 computers to be ensured legal. My point is **RSA can only ensure 1 of them legal, instead of both of them.**
>
> Another important thing is cracker **CAN** also use private key to encrypt and public key to decrypt. The key can make client know it was connecting to a "legal" server, but can't help server to ensure it's a "legal" client since key stored at client side or send from server can be leaked. A better solution is implement your own hash algorithm to prevent being hacked.
>
> Here is an article about RSA private key encryption:
>
> http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38739/RSA-Private-Key-Encryption
>
> Let's think about bank website, the client should know he is on legal website, but bank server doesn't need to ensure the client is legal or not since mobile phone authentication and other methods can do the trick. The mobile phone authentication is just something like "hash method", so, **hash method is a must**. RSA alone can not ensure safety.
>
> Without hash method, if a cracker gets key stored, or transmitted by Internet, he can easily make a fake client without any difficulties.

**Well, then what's your solution?**

> Since I'm implementing a Client-Server based software, I can share you my solution:
>
> 1. I saved private key into Client's source code.
> 2. When server send some response or client send some request, use private/public key to encrypt and decrypt by the other side.
> 3. You need some protection, like code obfuscation to protect the key stored in client.
> 4. You need to design an **hash algorithm** to ensure data sent by client is legal. The hacker might get your key finally, but hard to know what your algorithm is so it's still safe enough.
> 5. **Hash algorithm** means an algorithm combined with add some salt/SHA-1/UUID/timestamp...etc. I don't mean you should invent a new encrypt algorithm.
>
> For example, if the plain text is `I'm so awesome`
>
> The algorithm can be:
>
> Result = SHA1(salt + plain text + timestamp + anything you like)
>
> If find your algorithm leaked, just change some key values.

**What if your hash algorithm leaked?**

> Remember there's no algorithm can not be hacked. **We don't need to build a castle can not be destroyed, we just need to make out enemy pay hard.**
>
> Still, you also need a quick "big red button" if anything goes wrong. Hash algorithm can play this role quite easy, a small modification can make crackers pay lots of time to hack it out. That's already **good enough**.

UPDATE:

> Is SSL equivalent to public-key encryption? Should I use it instead?

Yes, but you still have to store key somewhere better than send it through network. `HTTPS/TLS` is another decent choice.

Comment: I understand.  So you physically store the key in the other application without sending it over the internet?

Comment: Don't put the private key in your code. They are **private** and should not be shared.

Comment: Also, don't design your own hash algorithm. Unless you have a doctorate in algebra, you will fail. And even if you do, you still might. Rule number 1 of cryptography: don't roll your own.

Comment: @BartFriederichs RSA algorithm is not as safe as you think since in Matthew's case he want both computer to be ensured "legal". It's quite easy for crackers to make a fake client if he got one of key.

Comment: If you want to ensure a certain website is who he say it is, use a signing scheme, not an encryption scheme. RSA also has possibilities to cryptographically sign data.

Comment: @BartFriederichs I said "hash algorithm", that means you can do a hash algorithm combined with add some salt/SHA-1/UUID/timestamp. You got the wrong point since I don't mean you should invent a new encrypt algorithm.

Comment: @ReckHou hash algorithms are a vital part of cryptography. You say "design an hash algorithm". Don't do that. Also, don't put private keys in code. Also, don't make your own implementation of existing algorithms. What you propose on the hash algorithm "change if leaked", how do you do that in C# code if the client is running on somebody's computer? Just using a salt is enough. You are relying a lot on "security through obscurity", which is not a good idea.

Comment: @BartFriederichs but you still need something to ensure what you received is legal, right? And you also need a quick "big red button" if anything goes wrong. Hash algorithm can play this role quite easy, and also make crackers pay lots of time to discover. That's already good enough.