# Handling OAuth Responses & Sessions

Tags: session, cookies, oauth, go

At the end of an OAuth2 token exchange, I'm [typically] left with a JSON array of user data that I've un-marshalled into a struct (say, GoogleUser) with the fields I care about.

What is the sensible way of recording that data to my DB? Just call a `CreateUser` function from the callback handler, pass the struct and save it (the obvious way to me), after checking that the user doesn't already exist in the DB?

I assume I should then create a session token (i.e. `session.Values["authenticated"] == true`) in the callback handler, store that in a cookie (with a reasonable expiry date) and simply just check for `if authenticated == true` on any handler functions that expect a logged-in user? Or, for admin handlers: `if admin_user == true`. **What are the risks here (if any)** presuming I'm talking over HTTPS and using secure cookies?

Apologies for the basic questions: just trying to get a grip on "best practice" ways to log users in w/ OAuth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regards to your first question, It's usually recommended to do the check and insert in a single transaction. It depends on what DB you're using, but these are usually referred to as `UPSERT` statements. In PLSQL it looks a bit like this (modify to taste):

```
CREATE FUNCTION upsert_user(emailv character varying, saltv character varying, hashv character varying, date_createdv timestamp without time zone) RETURNS void
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$;
BEGIN
    LOOP
        -- first try to update the key
        UPDATE users SET (salt, hash) = (saltv, hashv) WHERE email = emailv;
        IF found THEN
            RETURN;
        END IF;
        -- not there, so try to insert the key
        -- if someone else inserts the same key concurrently,
        -- we could get a unique-key failure
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO users(email, salt, hash, date_created) VALUES (emailv, saltv, hashv, date_createdv);
            RETURN;
        EXCEPTION WHEN unique_violation THEN
            -- do nothing, and loop to try the UPDATE again
        END;
    END LOOP;
END;
$$;
```

In regards to your second question, *usually* `Secure` cookies over HTTPS is enough. I'd set the `HttpOnly` option, and usually the `Path` option as well.

`HttpOnly` means that the cookie can't be accessed by JS (only HTTP or HTTPS), and the `Path` option allows you to specify what path (in the URL) the cookie is valid for.

Comment: Great; thanks very much. I'm using RethinkDB, which does support upserts (just without the SQL syntax): https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/209. Thanks for answering my second question as well: my understanding is that the only risk I truly run with cookies are replay attacks, but I plan to have a sane expiry (7 days) to limit this. As long as users cannot impersonate an admin, or another user, then I'm not overly concerned.

Comment: I think an expiry time as short as 30-60 minutes for the admin users is probably a good idea. They can do a lot more damage!

So... do I get the bounty? :-) It's cool if you want to wait for a better answer or more info.

Comment: (I had to wait 12 hours to give it out) ;)

Answer (score 1):

The `Access Token` in `OAuth` standard have a expiry. It's usually determined by authorization server. In your case I assume you are on authorization server side.

Read [RFC 6750](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750#section-4) for example:

> Typically, a bearer token is returned to the client as part of anOAuth 2.0 [RFC6749] access token response.  An example of such a response is:

```
 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
 Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
 Cache-Control: no-store
 Pragma: no-cache

 {
   "access_token":"mF_9.B5f-4.1JqM",
   "token_type":"Bearer",
   "expires_in":3600,
   "refresh_token":"tGzv3JOkF0XG5Qx2TlKWIA"
 }
```

Also read concept of `Access Token` in [RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.4):

> The access token provides an abstraction layer, replacing different
> authorization constructs (e.g., username and password) with a single
> token understood by the resource server.  This abstraction enables
> issuing access tokens more restrictive than the authorization grant
> used to obtain them, as well as removing the resource server's need
> to understand a wide range of authentication methods.

So in your case, I don't think a "cookie" or "admin handler" is needed. You only have to generate `Access Token` & `Refresh Token` for each users logged in just like `OAuth` spec says, and store its expiry as well. You can also provide a hash method related with `Access Token` to make sure it's a  legal request. For example, users use their access token to generate a signature with hash & salt method, send access token & signature to server to verify. Read [Public Key Encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15985401/public-key-encryption/) for more details.

Furthermore, you don't need to save these tokens into your DB because they are all temporary resources. You can also save all user informations in memory and implement a cache layer to save these informations which truly important into DB periodically(which I'm currently using now) to lower DB pressure.

Comment: My question may have been unclear: I'm implementing an OAuth2 *client*, and I'm trying to determine the 'best practice' method of handling a response from Google|GitHub|etc. once I get a JSON array with the user's data (name, email, id, avatar, etc). I'm also trying to determine the best way to authenticate a user when they are attempting to access a "private" page; using session cookies seems like the best fit here.